# SQL Select Duplicate Issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using an Oracle database. My SQL runs, but is bringing back a duplicate result. The RPA_To_Lapse column is setting a flag if a member has a contact log with a certain category/sub category. The member is coming back as both a yes and a no because there is a log that meets the criteria and a log that doesn't meet the criteria. 
It is company policy to create the joins in the where clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ppd.group_id, 
                p.mem_no                                         AS 
                Main_Member_No, 
                p.policy_no, 
                'N'                                              AS 
                Mixed_Policy_Ind, 
                'Y'                                              AS Renewal, 
                p.policy_eff_dt                                  AS 
                Effective_Date, 
                p.policy_eff_dt                                  AS Lapse_Date, 
                'Left company – Individual cover not retained' AS Lapse_Reason 
                , 
                'Don’t print anything' 
                AS Lapse_Pack_Type, 
                ppc.payment_method, 
                ppc.payment_frequency, 
                ( CASE 
                    WHEN ( ppc.payment_method = 'CQ' 
                           AND ppc.payment_frequency = '1' ) 
                          OR ( css_log_cat IN ( '001' ) 
                               AND css_log_sub_cat IN ( 'OT5', '00L' ) ) THEN 
                    'N' 
                    ELSE 'Y' 
                  END )                                          AS RPA_To_Lapse
FROM   vw_pol p, 
       cd_pol_mem_det mpl, 
       cd_pol_cont ppd, 
       cd_pol_cont_det ppc, 
       cd_group g, 
       cd_cont_log_mem clm, 
       cd_cont_log_detail_mem cldm
WHERE  p.policy_status IN ( 'C' ) 
       AND mpl.member_status = 'A' 
       AND p.policy_no = mpl.policy_no 
       AND p.policy_no = ppc.policy_no 
       AND p.mem_no = clm.log_caller_id (+) 
       AND clm.contact_log_id = cldm.contact_log_id (+) 
       AND p.mem_no IN (SELECT mem_no 
                        FROM   vw_pol 
                        WHERE  policy_lapse_reason = 
           'Left company - cover retained on Individual basis' 
           AND policy_lapse_dt = To_date('23/10/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy' 
                                 )) 
       AND p.mem_no IN (SELECT log_caller_id 
                        FROM   cd_cont_log_mem clm, 
                               cd_cont_log_detail_mem cldm 
                        WHERE  clm.contact_log_id = cldm.contact_log_id 
                               AND css_log_cat IN ( '001' ) 
                               AND css_log_sub_cat IN ( 'OT5', '00L' )) 
       AND p.policy_no = ppd.policy_no 
       AND mpl.member_activity_start_dt <= Trunc(SYSDATE) 
       AND mpl.member_activity_end_dt >= Trunc(SYSDATE) 
       AND mpl.member_activity_start_dt >= ppd.contract_start_dt 
       AND mpl.member_activity_end_dt <= ppd.contract_end_dt 
       AND mpl.member_activity_start_dt >= ppc.contract_activity_start_dt 
       AND mpl.member_activity_end_dt <= ppc.contract_activity_end_dt 
       AND Trunc(SYSDATE) BETWEEN ppd.contract_start_dt AND ppd.contract_end_dt 
       AND g.group_id = ppd.group_id
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: I can't upload documents to Stack Overflow, don't see why there is a down vote

Comment: This join policy asks for trouble (and hard-to-read queries). You have somewhat of a half-cartesian join with multiple `cd_pol_mem_det` and multiple `cd_pol_cont` per `vw_pol`. Do you want to show all combinations of `cd_pol_mem_det` and `cd_pol_cont` per policy? Then you even join `cd_pol_cont_det` on `policy_no` only. Shouldn't a row in `cd_pol_cont_det` reference a row in `cd_pol_cont` rather than `vw_pol`?

Comment: Appreciate the join readability issues, so my initial query without the two cont tables worked fine. It's when I add them the problem occurs. They bring back duplicates of each other because the cont tables holds two records, one the criteria I'm looking for and then another record without the criteria. My query then brings back the same member twice if that makes sense?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: You mean the tables `cd_pol_cont` and `cd_pol_cont_det`? What table do the columns `css_log_cat` and `css_log_sub_cat` belong to? BTW: It looks like the table `cd_group`, `cd_cont_log_mem`, and `cd_cont_log_detail_mem` are superfluous in the query and can be removed from it.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, simplify the problem: [mcve].

Comment: BTW, no need to upload any documents, most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text - not as images.

Comment: @jarlh: "It is company policy to create the joins in the where clause." But I agree, I'd probably write proper queries first and only convert them to pre-1992 joins in the last step for company rules sake, if I were working for that company.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes those columns. They belong to cd_pol_cont_det, but I need cd_pol_cont  to link the rest of the query. Thank you they potentially can be removed (I may need to reference columns from these at a later date though)

Comment: @jarlh I think my issues is simple (just difficult to explain). I'm setting a flag if a member has a contact log with a certain category/sub category. That member is coming back as both a yes and a no because there is a log that meets the criteria and a log that doesn't meet the criteria.

Comment: If it is that simple, you can remove lots of stuff from your question. (I never answer questions where I have to scroll to read it all.)

Comment: On a side note: `SELECT DISTINCT` is almost always a sign for an inadequate query you are trying to "rescue" ;-) Rather than using `DISTINCT` right away, you should look at the joins to see what is leading to duplicate result rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you merely want to look up `cd_pol_cont_det` whether a match exists or not. So use `EXISTS`. Something along the lines of

```
select ...
  ppc.payment_frequency ,
  case when exists
  (
    select null 
    from cd_pol_cont_det pcd
    where pcd.policy_no = p.policy_no
    and 
    (
      (pcd.payment_method = 'CQ' and pcd.payment_frequency = 1)
      or
      (pcd.css_log_cat in ('001') and pcd.css_log_sub_cat in ('OT5', '00L'))
    )
  ) then 'N' else 'Y' end as rpa_to_lapse 
from vw_pol p ...
```

Comment: Thanks, apologies I mis read the tables in your previous comment. The tables that hold the contact log details are cd_cont_log_mem clm,  cd_cont_log_detail_mem cldm. Clm having log caller id and cldm having category and sub category

Comment: Then adjust my answer to the tables involved. If joins lead to duplicates, then don't join. Use `[NOT] EXISTS` instead.